# Is a Sapphire HD5850 still a good but power hungry Graphics Card in 2019?

Tags: graphics-card

I live a bit under a rock as far as up-to-date tech goes.  Is a Sapphire HD5850 still a good graphics card in 2019 ?  From what I can tell it was cutting edge in about 2011.  It won't be used in a gaming rig, but in a workstation used for graphic design (specifically to run the Adobe Creative Cloud suite of products).

The box says "DDR5" and 2 teraFLOPS of power using one X16 PCI Express Slot.  It sounds impressive.  Is it ?  Was it ?

And possibly another more general question.  Have CPUs and GPUs changed all that much in terms of "raw power" over the last few years ?  From what I understand the emphasis has been more on reducing power consumption (but the "raw power" hasn't changed all that much).

If I look at the box it says a 500 Watt or greater power supply is needed with two 75W 6-pin PCI Express power connectors needed.  So maybe this is (still ?) a pretty good card - but it is just really power hungry ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *really* dependent on the exact situation.  There are three 'issues' with it:

- It's got next to no processing power.

  For a simple web browser and word processing setup that most people who aren't gaming need, this thing is more than sufficient (it's actually overkill, I'd go with a GeForce 210 or even just an iGPU for something like that).  For your use case though, it's probably going to be an issue.  Most Adobe software makes very heavy use of GPU-based hardware acceleration to be able to run efficiently (they technically don't need to, they just care *way* too much about their software looking nice).  There used to be an option to disable hardware acceleration in some Adobe products, and if there still is for the ones you want to use, it may actually speed up the software in your case if you have a good enough CPU (though if that's the case, don't waste your money and power budget on an HD5850)
- It doesn't have support for hardware acceleration of the newest video codecs.

  This probably won't be an issue for your usage unless you're doing lots of video editing or want to watch stuff on streaming services while working.  Just like the first point, you can make up for this by just having a great CPU.
- It's got horrible power efficiency by today's standards.

  This is the biggest issue here.  'Modern' cards (one or two generations old) can do just as much as an HD5850 using less than a fifth of the power.  If you're actively going to be using this system and actually pushing the GPU (and it sounds like that's your plan), you will actually *save* money in the long run by just shelling out the money for a more modern card.

---

A bit more background:

Just because a GPU is old doesn't make it 'bad', just like I mentioned above it depends on your primary use case.  What you need to consider is whether it covers the display capabilities you need, and whether it ends up making sense to get something newer or not based on power consumption and overall cost.

As an example of this, where I work we use a lot of NVIDIA GeForce 210's (decade old card) because they're cheap, reasonably energy efficient (roughly 75W, so they need nothing special from the PSU), and are more than sufficient for basic office usage that we need (web browser, email, word processor/spreadsheet, and database software).  It just doesn't make sense for us to shell out hundreds of dollars on a fancy GPU for people who won't actually utilize even a tenth of it's capabilities.

Going even further back in vintage, I personally still use Trident Blade3D cards with some regularity (20 years old roughly) because I have a lot of systems that only need SVGA text-mode to work, and the cards are effectively free for me because I've got about four dozen of them lying around (I bough a bunch in bulk a couple years back, they're great for adding a basic GPU to old hardware, and I deal with a lot of old hardware), so there's not really any point in me even shelling out the money for GeForce 210's.

---

In your particular case, I'd suggest looking into something like an NVIDIA Quadro K420.  They're sufficient for most Adobe software (again, excluding real-time video editing, if you're doing that you *need* the best GPU you can get), *way* more energy efficient than the HD5850 (which means you can get a less expensive power supply too), and not particularly expensive.

Comment: Thank you very much - I was after a few big picture musings like this.  I like your comments around 'old doesn't mean bad'.  In this case, the card will be going into an old MacPro (big metal box, 32GB of Ram, SSD with spinning disks too - horribly power hungry in itself).  So cutting edge isn't exactly important (I run Windows 8.1 on it because Windows 10 updates are too frequent for me!).  I also like how you've put a couple of other vintage tech graphics options there.  Thank you for your time - Patrick

Answer (score 1):

> From what I can tell it was cutting edge in about 2011. It won't be used in a gaming rig, but in a workstation used for graphic design (specifically to run the Adobe Creative Cloud suite of products).

Adobe products only support specific cards, in order to use it for hardware acceleration (GPU), the card you are asking about isn’t supported by Adobe.  This means the card wouldn't serve any purpose within an Adobe product.  For the purpose of this activity, the card is not useful.

> It would be useless for Creative Cloud and Blender activities.

1 GB VRAM is not adequate enough for Blender activities in 2019.

> it would only be driving a monitor at 1080p

It might be able to do this.  You should make sure the card supports this resolution before you purchase it.

> It sounds impressive. Is it? Was it?

In 2011 it was impressive.  In 2019, it is 7x slower, when calculating 32-bit floating point calculations. This is an assumption is that the 2 Teraflops is a number associated with 32-bit floating point calculations (FP32).  If it is FP16 instead, that means it has even worst FP32 performance, since FP16 is typically higher.

> Have CPUs and GPUs changed all that much in terms of "raw power" over the last few years?

In most cases, this indeed has been the case, a CPU is more efficient in both in terms of raw computational power and the amount of power it requires compared to a CPU release 8 years ago.

In most cases, due to advancement in technology, it is difficult to compare a GPU released in 2011 to a GPU released in 2019. The capability, of an RTX 2080 Ti, cannot easily be compared to something as weak as the Sapphire HD5850.

> If I look at the box it says a 500 Watt or greater power supply is needed with two 75W 6-pin PCI Express power connectors needed. So maybe this is (still ?) a pretty good card - but it is just really power hungry?

The `Sapphire HD5850` is not a good card.  I cannot think of a single purpose, where it would be a benefit, to have such a weak card in your system.

Comment: Good to use as a space heater.